# How do I make vim-style key bindings work on tmux using set-window-option?

Tags: tmux

I am aware that I can manually bind individual keys in my `.tmux.conf` file, but [according to this page](http://blog.sanctum.geek.nz/vi-mode-in-tmux/) I should be able to get vim-like key bindings in tmux simply by adding the following to my `.tmux.conf`, saving me having to maintain a list of keybindings:

`set-window-option -g mode-keys vi`

But this doesn't really seem to work as expected. Sure enough, when I press `Ctrl+b [` I am able to navigate through my terminal history using vim keys `hjkl`, but when I press `Ctrl+b k` it doesn't take me to the above window, for that I still have to press `Ctrl+b Up`, same goes for down, left and right.

Why doesn't this work? Do I really have to map these keys manually on top of vi mode to get *actual* vi mode?

I'm using `tmux 1.6`

Comment: Situation is the same in tmux 1.8. :set-window-option command is not understood by the tmux command line. Kent's fix below provides most of what I wanted, though.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

add this to your cnofig:

```
#switch panels
bind k selectp -U # switch to panel Up
bind j selectp -D # switch to panel Down 
bind h selectp -L # switch to panel Left
bind l selectp -R # switch to panel Right
```

Comment: I am afraid that so far (v1.9a) what you are hoping to have doesn't exist yet. well, you can dl the and change the source to compile one customized tmux though. @Jason